# Margin in a clear both container not being applied

Tags: css, css-float, margin

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class = "content_wrapper">
    <div class = "left_side">
        LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
    </div>
    <div class = "right_side">
        RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
    </div>
    <div class = "bottom">
        bottom content
    </div>
</div>
```

The following CSS:

```
#content_wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.left_side{margin:0px; width:100px; padding:0px 0 0 5px; float:left;}
div.right_side{margin:0px; width:100px; padding:0px 0 0 5px; float:right;}
div.bottom {clear:both; margin-top:20px;}
```

And the following question:

How can I make the bottom div have some margin from the content wrapper container?

You can see it live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8YN6/10/) , that the margin is not being applied.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `float:left` to div.bottom the margin will work. If you do not wish to use float, padding-top{20px) will work like Koby mentioned.

Also in your HTML you have `<div class="contentWrapper">` but in your CSS #content_wrapper.. change that to .content_wrapper {

Answer (score 0):

change HTML into:

```
<div class = "content_wrapper">
    <div class = "left_side">
        LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
    </div>
    <div class = "right_side">
        RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;" />
    <div class = "bottom">
        bottom content
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS into:

```
#content_wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.left_side{margin:0px; width:100px; padding:0px 0 0 5px; float:left;}
div.right_side{margin:0px; width:100px; padding:0px 0 0 5px; float:right;}
div.bottom {margin-top:20px;}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/L8YN6/11/
​

Comment: Can't I do that with just css instead of adding a new html element??

Answer (score 0):

What about using padding-top instead of margin-top ? it will push the content of the div 20px to the bottom:

div.bottom {clear: both; padding-top:20px;}

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this a little differently, using a separate but reusable "clearing" element: http://jsfiddle.net/L8YN6/16/

```
<div class = "content_wrapper">
    <div class = "left_side">
        LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
            LEFT SIDE<br>
    </div>
    <div class = "right_side">
        RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
                RIGHT SIDE<br>
    </div>
    <div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class = "bottom">
        bottom content
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS becomes:

```
#content_wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.left_side {margin:0px; width:100px; padding:0px 0 0 5px; float:left;}
div.right_side {margin:0px; width:100px; padding:0px 0 0 5px; float:right;}
div.clearing { clear: both; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; overflow: hidden; }
div.bottom { margin-top: 20px }
```

​I prefer this approach to wrestling with different browser's interpretations of the "float" specification for CSS. Alternatively, you could employ the [self-clearing floats](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By doing that, aren't we breaking the separation of content vs styling? I mean, that element is just for styling purposes right?

Comment: @HommerSmith: Yes, it's just for styling. It's ugly and intrusive, but it does exactly what it's supposed to, and I prefer it over wrestling with CSS floats.

Comment: If you're going to take this approach, you can just add "div.right_side + div.bottom { clear: both; }" and get rid of the div with the nbsp and its associated div.clearing css.